# Lookup returning #n/a - would like cell to be blank

Tags: vlookup

I am using this formula to look across multiple sheets and return the value:

=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SheetList,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!a2:a100"),A2)>0,0))&"'!a2:e100"),3,0)

where there is no data to return #N/A is returned, How can I have that cell remain blank instead?

Answer (score 4):

Excel has a function `IFNA()` for exactly this purpose.

`=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(SheetList,MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!a2:a100"),A2)>0,0))&"'!a2:e100"),3,0),"")`

The formula above wraps yours into an `IFNA` with the result if NA being blank. (note the addition at the end.)  You could also have it return something else, like "invalid" or "none" or even the results of a different formula.

Answer (score 1):

Add a test to your formula:

```
=if(isblank(cellreference),"",yourformula)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell to whiteout using conditional formatting by setting condition to "Formula Is", the formula to "=ISERROR(cell(s))" [cells are the cell or range of cells you want to check for an error value], and setting the format to a white text color.  This work on any error, including the one in question.

You could also use "=ISNA(cell(s))" to only white out on the #N/A error and not on the other errors.

Conditional formatting copies with the cell so create the first cell, set the conditional formatting, then copy it around as needed.